# create_links() in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I tried to give pagination it is not appearing in desired location. There is no error messages coming.What is wrong in this code I am unable to find it.
Is there anything I am missing?
This is my controller - method:

```
public function courses()
{
    $this->load->library('pagination');


    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('courses_tbl');
    $this->db->join('course_category_tbl', 'courses_tbl.course_category_id = course_category_tbl.id');
    $this->db->limit(6, $this->uri->segment(2));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $data['courses'] = $query->result();

    $total_records = $this->db->get('courses_tbl');

    $config['base_url'] = base_url("courses/");
    $config['total_rows'] = $total_records->num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 6;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';

    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';

    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $config['cur_tag_open'] = "<li class=\"active\"><span><b>";
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = "</b></span></li>";

    $this->pagination->initialize();

    $this->load->view('courses',$data);
}
```

This is my view :
    echo $this->pagination->create_links();

Comment: You miss this attribute `$config`; You should change this to `$this->pagination->initialize($config);`

Comment: Where am I missing?

Comment: You should change this line `$this->pagination->initialize();` to `$this->pagination->initialize($config);`

Comment: Thanks it worked. But now it is giving me not found when I click on the next page button.

Comment: What type of url showing? Please attach the url.

Comment: the docs for pagination are pretty extensive and well written i suggest you look over them as i don't think you have everything setup properly. just go through 1 by 1.

Comment: http://localhost/tt.in/courses/6 that goes to this

Comment: Thanks Alex I did that and it helped me a lot.

Comment: also note that you can get your uris via `function courses($page = null)` and `somesite.com/courses/6` will populate $page with 6.